# ThinkingSphinx config match_mode and distributed index problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, distributed, thinking-sphinx

Have been struggling with ThinkingSphinx 3.0.5 for a couple of days. basically,

1. we use distributed indexes, so for one model 4 indexes were defined.

   ```
   index post_core
   {
     type = distributed
     local = post_core_i0
     local = post_core_i1
     local = post_core_i2
     local = post_core_i3
   }
   ```
2. how to make TS search to point to this distributed index? `:index => 'post_core'` doesn't seem to work.
3. We need a custom parameter like `dictionary = /home/user1/../my.txt` in the final config file -- how to make `rake ts:configure` to keep it?
4. how to set match mode to any? `:match_mode => :any` doesn't work

Thanks!